# How do I /fill blocks in a certain direction in Minecraft 1.16?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

So, I'm attempting to create an attack for a boss fight I'm making.  The boss can spawn a square of redstone blocks and dispensers which contain arrows. I want the dispensers to face **west**.

So I type this command:

```
fill 1994 143 1972 dispenser{Facing:west,Items:[{id:"arrow",Count:64b,Slot:0b}],}
```

The result looks like:
[image: Dispensers.]

The dispensers are facing **north**.

No matter what I put for Facing, the dispensers are always facing north and I can't do anything about it.

Is there a way I can fix this?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

There’s a difference between block states which are denoted by `[]` and NBT data denoted by `{}`.

Block states are the things that you can see when you open the f3 menu, and `facing` is a block state, not NBT data. Try something like this instead:

```
fill x1 y1 z1 x2 y2 z2 dispenser[facing=west]{Items:[...]}
```

Comment: I'm unable to use x, y and z 2 as it just turns red when I type them in

Comment: Those are just temporary values. Replace them with the x y and z coordinates of the two corners that you want to fill between

Comment: As a separate solution, hold control while pressing your Pick Block key to copy any NBT data a block has. Doing this will also copy the items inside of a dispenser